# Cutting MKV files without recompression

Tags: matroska, video-editing

I'd like to cut out clips from an .mkv video.

How can I do that, without recompressing the file?

Comment: related: [Lossless cutting of MPEG TS files in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/383161/241386)

Answer (score 3):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) supports MKV, and should let you capture a given portion of the input file without transcoding.

Remember that MKV is just a container, so you may need to set the output video and audio codecs to match the input.

For example, to cut out 20 seconds starting from 1:50 minutes, use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:01:50 -c copy -t 20 output.mkv
```

The `-ss` option can be placed in front of `-i`, resulting in faster copying but less accuracy. If you experience out-of-sync audio or video, you're going to have to re-encode the file though:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -ss 00:01:50 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -t 20 output.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

[Boilsoft's MKV splitter](http://www.boilsoft.com/videosplitter/mkv-splitter.html) is what you need

> Boilsoft Video Splitter is very powerful MKV Splitter and MKV Cutter, split MKV, cut MKV without re-encode, So It is very fast and without any quality loss.

Comment: I have tried this application, it does not support mkv so well, although it claims it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tool called MVK Cutter. You can download it [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MKV-Cutter). Basically you can open a MKV file and start cutting unwanted parts.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to Recommend Software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) then [edit] your answer to include at least the minimum required information (the items in **bold**). Posts without this information may be subject to deletion. Thanks for contributing.