# Lossless cutting of MPEG TS files in Windows

Tags: windows, video-editing

I have several HD video files in transport stream (.ts) format, recorded with my satellite receiver.

I want to cut them, as in simply remove a few minutes from the beginning, the end and sometimes a few minutes in the middle of it (remove early start of recordings, late ends and, for some seldom files, the ads).

What is a good, ideally but not necessarily free, software with a GUI to do this?
Best would be something where you could select points on a timeline and simply cut the elements out.

As a resulting file, just the same .ts format would be great, but I could also live with putting the video contents into another container, as long as the video is NOT re-encoded / transcoded.

The files have additional audio streams and subtitles. These should be retained in the process.

My OS is Windows.

Comment: Would be great if you mentioned your OS. And, [what have you already tried?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software) I believe most NLEs should work, only importing the TS format might be a bit troublesome. You might need to change the container before. Can you run [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) to check what codec is used inside?

Comment: Oh, and you don't want to re-encode anything in this process?

Comment: OS is Windows (added above), and if possible I want to avoid re-encoding, because I don't want to loose quality. - What does NLE stand for?

Comment: I'm inclined to say this is an almost exact duplicate of [What is the best software to split and join avi files?](http://superuser.com/questions/9048/what-is-the-best-software-to-split-and-join-avi-files/9053#9053) — you'd only have to find out how to import the transport stream. NLE is a non-linear editor.

Answer (score 8):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) maybe the simplest solution for you. It can copy/remux from stream to stream without re-encoding. Just remember that you select **Copy** in the video output instead of any codecs, and the *start marker* **must be at an [I-frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types)**

The frame type is displayed beside clip time, as you can see `Frame type: I-FRM (00)` in the below screenshot (although the actual format may be changed, for example `Frame:I(02)` in older versions)

[image: keyframe avidemux]

You can also quickly select the I-frame by select the **next/prev key frame** buttons (shortcut: <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>)

The reason is that a video file is split into [group-of-pictures (GOPs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_of_pictures) that are encoded independently of each other, and contain pictures/frames in the stream. Each GOP starts with an I-frame (A.K.A key frame) which is a full image without any interpolation, followed by B or P frames. So when you start with an I-frame, the whole GOP can be copied to the output file without re-encoding

[image: GOP structure]

However for the last GOP it might not work for some codecs if we don't copy the whole GOP (although I'm not quite certain of this). That said, from my experiments it works without problem regardless of the *end marker* position. But if you get any errors on that, just select the end of the GOP by selecting the next key frame, then go back exactly one frame

You can also use any other software that supports direct stream copy, like [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.org/) or [FFMpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1)

- [cut video and save as direct stream copy](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/345566-cut-video-and-save-as-direct-stream-copy)
- [Simple lossless video editor for Windows with MP4 support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/21788/3579)
- [How to Cut/Edit Video Without Re-encoding](https://youtu.be/tZTjG8QI1SE)
- [Virtualdub Direct Stream Copy - Friday Minis 138](https://youtu.be/tZTjG8QI1SE)

Answer (score 4):

The absolute best program for this is [VideoReDo](http://www.videoredo.com/en/index.htm), but a little pricey. I haven't been able to find a free program to even approximate VideoReDo, but [TSSniper](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/TSSniper) can do in a pinch.

Answer (score 0):

I use *MPEG Streamclip* to cut the commercials out of the MPEG-TS recordings of my DVR.

MPEG Streamclip is available in a Windows version: http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-win.html -- although I must admit that I have only been using the OS X version so far.

Answer (score -1):

[Cuttermaran](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Cuttermaran) looks like the software program you're looking for. It also doesn't have a complicated GUI. However, it required that you have separate audio/video streams.

That shouldn't be an issue though as you can separate the audio/video streams easily using other software like [TsRemux](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/TsRemux).